# Regex combination for code optimization

Tags: regex

Is it possible to combine these criterias using regex?

Contain at least 8 characters and include at least three of the following:

- Upper case alpha (A-Z)
- Number (0-9)
- Lower case alpha (a-z)
- Special character (,!$%^&*()_+|~-=`{}[]:";'<>?,/)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to optimise the code for? In general, you should optimise for simplicity, which means *not* combining these in one regex.

Comment: "*at least 3 out of*" is one of the things where regex sucks. Better evaluate each criterion on its own, and write your business rules in your host language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.
The regex engine you use has to support conditionals `(?(cond)yes|no)`

That being said, if you go with any other character, the dot `.` is used.

```
^(?=.{8})(?:.*?(?:(?(1)(?!))([A-Z])|(?(2)(?!))([a-z])|(?(3)(?!))([0-9])|(?(4)(?!))([!"#$%&'()*+,\-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~]))){3,4}.*$
```

https://regex101.com/r/Iyj5hJ/1

Expanded

```
 ^                                             # BOS
 (?= .{8} )                                    # At least 8 chars
 (?:                                           # Require 3 out of the 4 types
      .*? 
      (?:
           (?(1)
                (?!)
           )
           ( [A-Z] )                                     # (1), Upper
        |  
           (?(2)
                (?!)
           )
           ( [a-z] )                                     # (2), Lower
        |  

           (?(3)
                (?!)
           )
           ( [0-9] )                                     # (3), Digit
        |  
           (?(4)
                (?!)
           )
           ( [!"#$%&'()*+,\-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~] )       # (4), Special
      )
 ){3,4}
 .* 
 $                                             # EOS
```

If you want to allow only non-whitespace in the ascii range, use this

```
^(?=.{8})(?:[a-zA-Z0-9!"#$%&'()*+,\-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~]*?(?:(?(1)(?!))([A-Z])|(?(2)(?!))([a-z])|(?(3)(?!))([0-9])|(?(4)(?!))([!"#$%&'()*+,\-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~]))){3,4}[a-zA-Z0-9!"#$%&'()*+,\-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~]*$
```

Expanded

```
 ^                                             # BOS
 (?= .{8} )                                    # At least 8 chars
 (?:                                           # Require 3 out of the 4 types
      [a-zA-Z0-9!"#$%&'()*+,\-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~]*? 
      (?:
           (?(1)
                (?!)
           )
           ( [A-Z] )                                     # (1), Upper
        |  
           (?(2)
                (?!)
           )
           ( [a-z] )                                     # (2), Lower
        |  

           (?(3)
                (?!)
           )
           ( [0-9] )                                     # (3), Digit
        |  
           (?(4)
                (?!)
           )
           ( [!"#$%&'()*+,\-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~] )       # (4), Special
      )
 ){3,4}
 [a-zA-Z0-9!"#$%&'()*+,\-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~]* 
 $
```

Comment: You didn't escape the `/` character in your special characters set.

Comment: @EganWolf - And it does not need escaping. It's not a _special character_. It only needs to be escaped if it's used as a string-regex delimiter, i.e. a regex literal (JS, Perl, or Php etc..). We/I only show regex in context. If it's raw (this is) what you see is what the _engine_ parses.